# Collapse Leaflet GroupedLayerControl with Exclusive Layers

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

Leaflet's supported plug-in **Leaflet.GroupedLayerControl** now supports exclusive grouped layers (via radio buttons similar to the baselayer functionality).

However, since the implementation of the exclusive grouped layers the isCollapsed call in **BootLeaf** no longer performs as expected when calling the exclusive layer groups. If uncalled, the baselayers and grouped layers still perform as expected but there is an issue as soon as the exclusive grouped layers are added to the code.

The code asks for the grouped layer control to collapse if the window is <= 767px otherwise if the window is larger to display the grouped layer control in its entirety:

```
       if (document.body.clientWidth <= 767) {
           var isCollapsed = true;   
       } else {
           var isCollapsed = false;   
       }


       var layerControl = L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays, options, {
            collapsed: isCollapsed  
       }).addTo(map);
```

Based on my initial trial and error it appears the existing changes cannot be modified to get the grouped layer control to open in windows that exceed a width of 767px and the only code changes in the Leaflet.GroupedLayerControl include essential exclusive groups code. I am guessing additional code is needed to ensure the exclusive layers are included with the grouped layer control.

For troubleshooting, please see: the ***[working JS fiddle WITHOUT exclusive layers](http://jsfiddle.net/hockeyduck30/ozafaybb/)*** and the ***[non-working JS fiddle WITH exclusive layers](http://jsfiddle.net/hockeyduck30/z9xq6e4j/)***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `collapsed: isCollapsed` to the options object like so:

`var options = {exclusiveGroups: ["Landmarks"], collapsed: isCollapsed};`